# PushApps register and unregister menu buttons

Tags: java, android, eclipse, pushapps

I setup my app to work with http://www.pushapps.mobi notifications API but I'm having trouble setting up a register and unregistered device button to enable and disable push notifications using menu setting.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.miplayer.app.MainActivity" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/register_push"
    android:title="@string/register_push"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/unregister_push"
    android:title="@string/unregister_push"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="@string/action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/itemRefresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/btnRefresh" />
```

```
//Push Notification//

    protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.feed_list);

        // Start PushApps and register to the push notification service (GCM)
        PushManager.init(getApplicationContext(), "208412738081", "93ea417b-cef4-42ac-b323-55f7b4c3536d");
        //optional - allows more than on notifications in the status bar, default is false
        PushManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setShouldStackNotifications(true);
        //optional - set a your own icon for the notification, defaults is the application icon
        PushManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setNotificationIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // optional - sets the source of the device id for identification, default is DeviceIDTypes.IMEI
        PushManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setDeviceIDType(DeviceIDTypes.ANDROID_ID);


 // optional - register for registration and unregistration events
        PushManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerForRegistrationEvents(new PushAppsRegistrationInterface() {

            @Override
            public void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
                Log.d("PushAppsDemo", "arg1 " + arg1);

            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
                Log.d("PushAppsDemo", "arg1 " + arg1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Context paramContext, String errorMessage) {
                Log.d("PushAppsDemo", "PUSHAPPS ERROR: " + errorMessage);
            }

        });
    }

    //pushapps register and unregister buttons
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu1(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


        MenuItem register = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.register_push);
        PushManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).register();

        return true;

    }
```

//end Push notification//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code it looks like you are trying to create your own `onCreate` method and call it `onCreate1`.

Rename the `onCreate1` to `onCreate` and it should solve the problem.

Same with the `onCreateOptionsMenu` callback method, it should be called `onCreateOptionsMenu` and not `onCreateOptionsMenu1`.